# A cli command to invalidate cloudfront cache using first alias

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cli

If we want to invalidate the cloudfront cache, then we need to actually get the distribution Id. I want to invalidate few paths based on alias. Is there any cli command to solve it.

Comment: Distribution ID is required to make invalidation.

Comment: I found a workaround of it. I am going to post it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to achieve this using a shell script. 
Finding a distribution Id using alias name.

https://github.com/viharm91/aws-cli-invalidate-cache-by-alias/blob/master/invalidate-cloudfront-cache-by-alias